# How to zip a folder

Tags: .net, vb.net, zip

I have a link. When user will click this button, I want to run some code that will zip a folder on my desktop and, start downloading it.

Folder path is `C:/users/dave/desktop/myFolder`

**in aspx file:**

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server">zip folder and download </asp:HyperLink>
```

**In aspx.vb file:**

How can I write code here that will zip a folder on my desktop and start downloading this zip folder? Is there way to do it without downloading extra libraries and plugins?

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem`

Then you can zip the folder using the following:

```
Dim tempFile = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName() + ".zip"
System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory("C:\temp\awesome", tempFile)
```

Then to download it, you can send it in the response:

```
Response.Buffer = false
Response.Clear()
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Desktop.zip")
Response.ContentType = "Application/zip"
Response.TransmitFile(tempFile)
Response.End()
```

Comment: FYI  You need .Net 4.5+.