# Zip a Folder Created in C#

Tags: c#, zip, dotnetzip

I'm creating a folder in C# and I'm hoping to zip it up as soon as I've created it. I've had a look around ([How to zip a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32140182/how-to-zip-a-folder)), (http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) but no luck so far. I'm a bit apprehensive of using dotnetzip as it's last release was 5 years ago.

Is dotnetzip still relevant in Visual Studio 2015 or is there a more modern way of zipping folders in C# without using a package?

This is how I'm copying the folders;

```
    private static void CopyDirectory(string SourcePath, string DestinationPath, bool overwriteexisting)
    {

        SourcePath = SourcePath.EndsWith(@"\") ? SourcePath : SourcePath + @"\";
        DestinationPath = DestinationPath.EndsWith(@"\") ? DestinationPath : DestinationPath + @"\";

        if (Directory.Exists(SourcePath))
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(DestinationPath) == false)
                Directory.CreateDirectory(DestinationPath);

            foreach (string fls in Directory.GetFiles(SourcePath))
            {
                FileInfo flinfo = new FileInfo(fls);
                flinfo.CopyTo(DestinationPath + flinfo.Name, overwriteexisting);
            }
            foreach (string drs in Directory.GetDirectories(SourcePath))
            {
                DirectoryInfo drinfo = new DirectoryInfo(drs);
                CopyDirectory(drs, DestinationPath + drinfo.Name, overwriteexisting);
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm looking to zip the created folder after this.

Comment: _"no luck so far"_ isn't really descriptive. Show your attempts and their results.

Comment: There's [ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485707%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in .Net 4.5

Comment: Look into [Compression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression(v=vs.110).aspx) with the specific topic of [ZipArchive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Comment: @stuartd Thanks for the answer. I've just tried using this but I'm getting an error: `The file already exists`. As far as I can see it needs a file to exist so that it can zip it?

Comment: I believe from the documentation that that error indicates that the **zip** file already exists.. - "If the archive already exists, an IOException exception is thrown ... "`destinationArchiveFileName` already exists""

Comment: @stuartd rather strange because it definitely doesn't. Thanks for the help I'll keep investigating. If you offer your comment as an answer I'll accept.

Comment: @CBreeze done, thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To zip a folder, the .Net 4.5 framework contains [ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485707%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string startPath = @"c:\example\start";
string zipPath = @"c:\example\result.zip";

ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);
```

Comment: but  OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, sourceBytes); will  all these files in one folder...how to preserve ?

Answer (score 3):

Just wanted to add my two cents to the post that you already accepted as the answer.
Let's say you have a folder structure:

```
C:\RootFolder
C:\RootFolder\Folder1
C:\RootFolder\Folder1\Folder1a
C:\RootFolder\Folder1\Folder1b
C:\RootFolder\file1.txt
C:\RootFolder\file2.txt
```

`ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory` is definitely the way to go. No 3-rd party libs required. You simply need to reference the `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem`

What I wanted to point out is:
You can either zip the entire *RootFolder* including it to the archive

```
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(@"C:\RootFolder", @"C:\RootFolder.zip", 
                            CompressionLevel.Optimal, true);
```

or the contents of the *RootFolder* without the folder itself

```
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(@"C:\RootFolder", @"C:\RootFolder.zip", 
                            CompressionLevel.Optimal, false);
```

The fourth parameter (bool includeBaseDirectory) gives us this **flexibility**.
Hope it helps someone.

Comment: but  OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, sourceBytes); will  all these files in one folder...how to preserve ?

Answer (score 0):

[How do I ZIP a file in C#, using no 3rd-party APIs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940582/how-do-i-zip-a-file-in-c-using-no-3rd-party-apis) covers the same ground and has solutions for both .Net 3.5 (https://stackoverflow.com/a/940621/2381157) and .Net 4.5 (https://stackoverflow.com/a/20200025/2381157) so I'm surprised that @kap states there is no .NET class for doing this.

Comment: Why the down vote?  The links to the duplicate question contain the same info as @stuartd provides and that's the accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can use third party dll ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib inside which you can compress directory using below load file to filsstream fs and proceed
bytes = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)zipFile.Write(buffer, 0, bytes)